Identify a kids' story about a boy with disfigured hands and super strength defeating alien invaders who use mind control
Please identify the story title, author and compilation book which I received as a Christmas gift in the early Nineties. There's at least two stories, one of which is a sci-fi story. I'll list aspects I am very certain about in boldface.

Published in UK in 1993 to 1996.
Protagonist is a boy in his late teens with badly scarred disfigured hands due to an industrial accident which he hides beneath leather gloves. As a result of this accident the protagonist has enhanced strength. He is invited to a Welsh holiday village by his friend. They enter a corner shop (convenience store) together where the proprietor is suspiciously friendly. When the protagonists leave the shop and touch the metal door handle, they get an electric shock and lose a short amount of time during which a tight orange/green plastic bracelet materialises on their wrist. The protagonist's super strength allows him to snap the bracelet off by pressing on it. The bracelet is some kind of mind control device that is controlling the other visitors to the village including the protagonist's friend. The protagonist's investigation ends with a climax where a secret tunnel inside this corner shop leads to an alien spacecraft where the villains are revealed to be aliens disguised as humans, and use the name Polidons. They are defeated by the protagonist.
Appeared in a large hardback yellow book approx 7 inches square with blue title lettering, as a mixed-activity book for children, almost certainly including a phrase similar to 'bumper book of activities and mazes' (It was bought for me specifically for the mazes, of which there weren't very many.)

I'm very certain of the name Polidons, but unfortunately there aren't any matches for that term online at all.
There is a second, unrelated, non sci-fi story in the same yellow book which might help to identify the compilation:

Two boys sneak into a cinema for a movie for which they are underage. They use theatrical makeup to disguise themselves as being older. One boy recommends a specific moustache to the other because of his '[something] nose and bullet chin'.
That's the entire second story. :)

I don't know the publisher or author. The book had puzzles and riddles and spot the differences and other things, but these are the two stories I can remember there being in the books.

The story is "Village of Fear" by Gavin Kier.  Despite it being obviously SF content, neither the story nor author is listed at ISFDb.
A search of the Internet Archive turns up the Bumper Fun Book for which it gives a 1999 date.  I haven't yet tracked down bibliographic information for it, but it does have hostile aliens called "Polidons" using mind-control bracelets:

The creature looked at him for a few moments. Then it spoke. "I am the leader of the people you see before you. We are the people of the Polidons. Soon we will be your masters!"

The hero, Mark, does have superhuman strength in his scarred hands:

He was looking forward to his few days' holiday with his friend. It would take his mind off his hands. He gripped the steering wheel with the lightest possible touch. He knew that the slightest pressure from his black-gloved hands would buckle and crush the wheel.
This amazing strength was part of an accident involving a new material. Mark had worked in a scientific institute. There had been an accident. To save valuable equipment and a fellow worker's life he had dragged away a container of active waste. He sealed it in a safety room and staggered out.
He awoke in hospital to find his hands horribly mutilated. It was thought that he would never use them again. But when he left hospital he found his hands had acquired a fantastic strength.
For the next few weeks he had to learn to control this strength. At first the things he tried to hold all crumbled. Finally he had managed to control this. But, as his hands were still terribly scarred and mutilated, he always wore skin-tight black gloves.

There is a shop that is putting orange bracelets on people that they can't get off, but Mark breaks his:

"Yes," said Bob, "it's about this wrist thing.  I wonder if you could get it off?"
The man looked at the orange bracelet.
"No, I can't," he said.  "Once that's on, you can't get it off."
He turned to Mark and said, "You're new here, sir.  How would you like one?"
"No, thank you," said Mark.
"You can have one for nothing," said the man, "seeing that you are a friend of Mr. Davies."
"No, thank you," said Mark again.
They turned to go.  The man went over to his counter and pushed a small button underneath.  As Mark grasped the door handle, a strange sensation shot through him.  He couldn't move.  It lasted only a few seconds, but when it ceased he was wearing one of the orange bracelets!
The man was backing away from him saying, "Thank you for changing your mind, sir."
Mark put two fingers round the strange bracelet.  He pressed it.  It cracked open and fell off.
"No, thank you," he said.

The cover of the IA copy matches your description, though other sources (e.g. Amazon) show an alternate cover.

The other story you refer to is "Night of Horror" by Robert Moss.

Thank you DavidW. This is clearly exactly what I recalled! Very nice work, I would love to know how you managed to find it? Especially when my attempts over the years have failed.

I can confirm that @user205694 (who posted the acceptance comment above) is the OP.
